# Django - Use Radio Buttons or Drop Down List for input

Tags: django, django-admin

I made a model something like this:

```
class Enduser(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

Now I want `user_type` to have only one of the given values, say any one from `['master', 'experienced', 'noob']`

Can I do this with Django?

Also, how can I display a list of radio buttons or drop-down list/select menu to chose one of these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `choices` attribute for `CharField`:

```
class Enduser(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
       (u'1',u'master'),
       (u'2',u'experienced'),
       (u'3',u'noob'),
       )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices=CHOICES)
```

This will save values `1,2 or 3` in the db and when retrieved the object, it will map it to `master, experienced or noob`. Take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) for more info.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

[Use model field choices:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
CHOICES = (
    ('foo', 'Do bar?'),
    ...
)
class Enduser(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=CHOICES)
```